# Razor Runtime Compilation doesn't work with dynamically loaded assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-class-library

I can't get Razor Runtime Compilation to work with a dynamically loaded assembly. My code:

**`Startup.cs`**

```cs
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(someModuleDllPath);
var viewsAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(someModuleViewsDllPath);

services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddApplicationPart(assembly)
    .AddApplicationPart(viewsAssembly)
    .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
            
services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options => { 
    options.FileProviders.Add(new EmbeddedFileProvider(assembly)); 
});
```

With this approach, I need to rebuild the loaded assembly project and restart the host to see changes. When I replace the last two lines with:

```cs
services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options => {
    options.FileProviders.Add(new PhysicalFileProvider(loadedAssemblyProjectContentRootPath)); 
});
```

I get the error:

> Cannot find compilation library location for package '<name of loaded assembly>'.

Setting `MvcRazorExcludeRefAssembliesFromPublish` to `false` doesn't change anything. The option with `PhysicalFileProvider` works when I add an explicit reference to the project.

I'm using .NET 5 and both projects have the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` type.

Is there any way I can make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the key of `PreserveCompilationContext`  was set to `false`.

[image]

And you should use the path under the current project, that is, the relative path, such as the following code:

```
services.Configure<MvcRazorRuntimeCompilationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.FileProviders.Add(new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(WebHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "..\\<name_of_loaded_assembly>")));
    options.AdditionalReferencePaths.Add(pluginAssembly.Location);
});
```

Comment: It seems like I needed to configure `AdditionalReferencePaths`. Thanks a lot, I've spent the whole day on this.

Comment: Any idea if it is possible to add additional reference paths after startup?